# Python manipulation of list of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings. The strings are delimited by a comma. Every 5th comma, I want to delete the comma itself and that string. This string may contain commas itself and may be different lengths, so I can't split the whole list based on that.

This is how the list looks like:

```
data = ['X, X, X, X, X, XXXXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX,
Y, Y, Y, Y, Y, YYYYYYY,YYYYY,YYYYYY']
```

The output I want is a list of lists with each string having split on the comma minus the strings after the 5th comma:

```
data = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just use `split()`

Comment: What do you mean by `may contain commas itself and may be different lengths`?

Comment: Too many unknowns. What I read: "I have a list of strings... Every 5th comma, I want to delete the comma itself and that string". So you just want to delete every string or what?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I mean, the string itself may have a comma but its a part of the string, such as "hi, how are you"

Comment: @szogoon yes, every 5th comma i want to delete what's between it and the next comma. however the string after the 5th comma is long and may contain a comma as part of the string

Comment: @user47467 that makes no sense. After the 5th comma, how are you supposed to know when to stop deleting?

Comment: @Gillespie this is why it's a problem!

Comment: Well if you don't know the answer, nobody does. This is your string, not ours. Are you wanting to split on whitespace and delete every sixth token?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
data  = [x.split(',')[0:5] for x in data]
```

---

Output :

```
[['X', ' X', ' X', ' X', ' X'], ['Y', ' Y', ' Y', ' Y', ' Y']]
```

Comment: That's true, but I like to put the 0 I find it more readable :)

Comment: I guess you also need to strip the spaces at the end?

Comment: thanks for your answer! i only get [['X', ' X', ' X', ' X', ' X']] as an output

Comment: Hmmm maybe I didn't get your question but your data is  ['X, X, X, X, X, XXXXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX,',
'Y, Y, Y, Y, Y, YYYYYYY,YYYYY,YYYYYY'] or is it a list only containing one string ?

Comment: @vlemaistre its a list with one string

Comment: Once you start deleting (after your 5 X) how do you know at which point you want to stop deleting and start saving again ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very limited information you given, I think you want something like:

```
s = 'X, X, X, X, X, XXXXXXXX,XXXXX,XXXX, Y, Y, Y, Y, Y, YYYYYYY,YYYYY,YYYYYY'
tokens = s.split(", ")

data = []
while tokens:
  data.append(tokens[:5])
  tokens = tokens[6:]

print(data)
```

See: https://repl.it/repls/UpsetTechnicalAdministration